# Need help to write two javascript functions in flot jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot

EDIT**********

I want help with writing the two functions "plotSingleCoverage" and plotAllCoverage below. The major problem I have is that I don't know how to search through all existing datasets on the page and then write out a single array in a dataset, or all array's of the same sort in different datasets. So if anyone could push me in the right direction I would be more than happy =)

Flot Examples

```
    <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>

    <p id="choices">Show:</p>

<a href="javascript:plotSingleCoverage('Test1')">Show coverage of first test</a>
<a href="javascript:plotAllCoverage()">Show coverage of all tests</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var Test1 = {
        "date": {
            label: "Date",
            data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
        },        
        "time": {
            label: "Time",
              data: [[1, 209], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 134]]
        },
       "modules": {
            label: "Modules",
             data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
        }, 
        "cases": {
            label: "Cases",
             data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
        }, 
        "failed": {
            label: "Failed",
              data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
        }, 
        "cover": {
            label: "Cover",
data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    }
}; 

var Test2 = {
        "date": {
            label: "Date",
            data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
        },        
        "time": {
            label: "Time",
              data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
        },
       "modules": {
            label: "Modules",
             data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
        }, 
        "cases": {
            label: "Cases",
             data: [[1, 101], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 45]]
        }, 
        "failed": {
            label: "Failed",
              data: [[1, 301], [2, 454], [3, 43], [4, 125]]
        }, 
        "cover": {
            label: "Cover",
        data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
        }
}; 

var Test3 = {
    "date": {
        label: "Date",
        data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    },        
    "time": {
        label: "Time",
          data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    },
   "modules": {
        label: "Modules",
         data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    }, 
    "cases": {
        label: "Cases",
         data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    }, 
    "failed": {
        label: "Failed",
          data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    }, 
    "cover": {
        label: "errover",
    data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    }
};

/*Need help to write this function, it shall go to that dataset that its argument is, for example in this case it shall go to Test1 and read that cover and plot it in the #placeholder*    
function plotSingleCoverage(coverageToPlot){
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [???]);
}
/*This function shall simply go through all avaible datasets and plot all cover array's*/
function plotAllCoverage(){
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [???]);
}

});
</script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: You might want to think about including a question.

Comment: You are starting to understand your problem, and that should lead you to understanding the solution. You have a few variables that you can't access in a convenient way. How about holding them in an array so you can loop on them easily and search for the right dataset to take actions on?

Comment: @Dvir Azulay OK so say that I do as you suggested and store everything in single variables, How do I search through the paga after a specific variable?

Say That I have

 var Software1Test1modules = [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]];
    var Software22Test45cases = [[1, 21], [2, 41], [3, 67], [4, 12]];

How do I search for "Software22Test45cases" on the webpage?? =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few variables that you can't access in a convenient way. How about holding them in an array so you can loop on them easily and search for the right dataset to take actions on? (from my comment above)

You can make an array of the available data sets like this: `var datasets = new Array();`.
Then, when defining a new dataset, do `datasets[] = { ...... }` instead of every `var Test1 = { ... };`.

```
var datasets = new Array();
datasets[0] = {
    "date": {
        label: "Date",
        data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    },        
    "time": {
        label: "Time",
        data: [[1, 209], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 134]]
    },
   "modules": {
        label: "Modules",
        data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    }, 
    "cases": {
        label: "Cases",
        data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    }, 
    "failed": {
        label: "Failed",
        data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    }, 
    "cover": {
        label: "Cover",
        data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    }
}; 

datasets[1] = {
    "date": {
        label: "Date",
        data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    },        
    "time": {
        label: "Time",
        data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    },
   "modules": {
        label: "Modules",
        data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    }, 
    "cases": {
        label: "Cases",
        data: [[1, 101], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 45]]
    }, 
    "failed": {
        label: "Failed",
        data: [[1, 301], [2, 454], [3, 43], [4, 125]]
    }, 
    "cover": {
        label: "Cover",
        data: [[1, 201], [2, 201], [3, 201], [4, 125]]
    }
};
```

Then, you could access the datasets like this:

```
alert(datasets[1]);
// datasets[0] holds the first test data, datasets[1] the second, and so on...
$.plot($("#placeholder"), datasets[0]);
```

Your plotSingleCoverage can then be:

```
function plotSingleCoverage(dateset){
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), dataset);
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
plotSingleCoverage(datasets[0]);
```

Comment: This was very useful, have one more question if you don't mind, your answer give access and plot the data date, time, modules, cases, failed, covered. But if I for instance want to only access the "cover" data in dataset[0], how do I accomplish that? Also say that I want to print out both "cover" in dataset[0] and dataset[1], how can I do that? Thank you so much =)

Comment: @Matt: Since we have the datasets in an `array`, we access them with their index in the array - `datasets[0]`, etc. But each dataset is an object - so we can access it like this: `alert(datasets[0].cover);` and `alert(datasets[0].cover.label);` and so on :)

BTW - Objects in JavaScript are basically associative arrays - you can also access the label of the cover of dataset 0 like this: `alert(datasets[0]["cover"]["label"]);`, but the first option is much more clear about the type of this element.

Comment: Wow thank you, one last question if you don't mind :P I had to change the name on "cover", "failed" to "Test1cover", "Test2cover" and "Test1failed" and "Test2failed" etc. Now if I want to access everything with "cover" in its label name, how can I do this? Like for example do a for loop going through all datasets and look for all labels containing "cover"? (if you wonder there are going to be around 20 diffrent, like datasets[19], so I can't use the alert(datasets[0]["cover"]["label"]); since the label wont be only "cover" anymore?. Thank you so much in advance yet again :D

Comment: @Matt: You can use the For..In statement in JavaScript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp
Basically, it allows you to iterate the properties of an object, without knowing what they are before doing that.
for your case, you can do `for (property in datasets[0]) { if (property.indexOf("cover") > -1) { /* this property contains the word "cover" and can be accessed through datasets[0][property] */ } }`.
You could chain that with a `for(var i=0; i < datasets.length; ++i){}` or any other method to loop on datasets :) JavaScript loops - http://www.webcheatsheet.com/javascript/loops.php

Comment: Thank you for all your efforts, they have been to great help =).